# require statement in express js throws a error

Tags: node.js, express

```
var express = require('express')
, signup = require('./routes/signup')
,login=require('./routes/login')  
, http = require('http')
, path = require('path')
, cal=require('./routes/calculate')
, db = require('./routes/db')

, ejs = require('ejs')
, moment = require('moment')
, mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = require('pooling');

var app = express();
pool.initializepool(10);


// all environments
 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

the var pool does not throw an error when this is mentioned in app.js. But when the same line is mentioned in smoother node js file it throws a error saying  Cannot find module 'pooling'.
this is my db.js file

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');
 var pool  = require('pooling');
 exports.validate= function(callback,email,password)
{
var connection=pool.getConnection();
var connection=connect();
  }
```

Please help

Comment: Please share your logs here

Comment: module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'pooling'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sachinhunur/Documents/workspace/samplenode/routes/db.js:5:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)

Comment: Seems like "pooling" module is not installed. Please do as "npm install pooling" than try again.

Comment: its not just this if i type var db = require('./routes/db'); it shows the same error. in app.js i can declare variables. but in any other node js file when i say require it throws a error. here pooling is a node js file that i have written

Comment: Pooling is a custom lib, so you have to require it in relative path, the path relative to the file you declare "require".

Comment: okay instead of pooling if i write my own node js file called cooling. So now if i write var pool= require(./routes/cpooling); it still throws a error.

Comment: is your file name is pooling.js or else

Comment: it was pooling.js now i changed it to  cpooling.js. I don't want to use custom library. I have defined my own functions for connection pooling which is present in cpooling.js. but when i say var pool=require(cpooling); it throws a error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure pooling is having a module.exports (which it must be having bcoz u r able to get it in app.js)

Then make sure relative path is correct like "./routes/login"

Hope this helps

```
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm
```